# How do i configure Squid as a Proxy in a private network?

Tags: proxy, squid

Here is the situation:

We have the following network:

DSL Modem - Switch  -  User 1, User 2,....

We want it to be:

DSL Modem - Squid Proxy Server - Switch - User 1, User 2,....

The endresult should be, that the endusers can login at their pc, without changing the configuration of their own pc, just as if they are linked directly to the dsl modem (through the switch). Furthermore it should be possible to logg their actions on the server.

Now squid can be configured in many ways, and I am confused which path to choose. Can anyone help me?

Twerp

Answer (score 1):

That's running Squid in a transparent proxy setup.

There are a number of good articles,

- http://www.deckle.co.za/squid-users-guide/Transparent_Caching/Proxy
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy.html
- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/71

Basically, you set the machine up with Squid as the network default gateway for your client machines (using DHCP) instead of the DSL modem.  You use the server to then route to and from the internet, with Squid transparently proxying the HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SOHO environnement you should prefere to use the Transparent Proxy method as said EightBitTony, with theLinux Iptable redirect method (redirect all HTTP/S transit to the 3389 port of the squid server.

If you are under Enterprise network (little one or bigger) you should have Cisco or Hp switch who support the WCCP Protocol method, which allow you to place your proxy on another lan than the client network and automatically redirect all traffic on the proxy and if the proxy is down the switch automatically redirect the traffic to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know WCCP only supports HTTP not HTTPS anyway transparent proxying of HTTPS is not possible. HTTPS is a end-to-end encryption. 
If you really want to get control of the HTTP/s traffic a transparent proxy is not the best choice. Better setup a normal proxy, denie traffic from all hosts to the internet except the proxy and configure the Browser with your proxy server settings in this case you can proxy HTTPS and maybe denie HTTPS traffic to specific sites.

Cheers